# onClick on li element are not passing target id properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a ReactJS project using MaterialUI. I have following code

```
{ this.state.categories.map((category, key) => (
      <List>
        <ListItem button id={key} onClick={this.handleClick}>
              <ListItemText primary={category.name} />
              {(category.id === Number(this.state.nestedOpenNum)) ? 
<ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItem>
      </List>
            )

      )}
```

and state looks something like

```
this.state = {
  open: false,
  nestedOpen: false,
  nestedOpenNum: 0,
  result: [],
  categories: [{
      id: 0,
      name: "COMPUER SCIENCE",
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "BUSINESS",
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "ART & HUMANITIES",
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "MATH & LOGIC",
    },{
      id: 4,
      name: "SCIENCE",
    }]
};
```

this is the handleClick function-

```
handleClick = (e) => {
this.setState({ nestedOpenNum: e.target.id });
this.setState({ nestedOpen: !this.state.nestedOpen });
console.log(e.target.id );
```

};

**PROBLEM**

When I click in padding area of li element(green area), everything working perfectly. But e.target.id is not passing when I click on li element(blue area).

[image]

how can I solve this?

Comment: can u create a codepen? it would be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should use `currentTarget` not `target`. Look at this https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11508#issuecomment-256045682

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the onClick handler as a prop to the ListItemText component, it looks to me like this component is blocking the other element from detecting its onClick handler.